# 2SB772 PNP SPICE model

Tags: npn, spice

I have trouble finding 2SB772 SPICE model. Can anyone help?

I can provide its complement NPN 2SD882 SPICE model

> .model Q2sd882 NPN(Is=282f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=100 Bf=200.7 Ise=288.7f Ne=1.368 Ikf=20 Nk=1.235 Xtb=1.5 Var=100 Br=52.37 Isc=8.515p Nc=1.527 Ikr=.2617 Rc=15.88m Cjc=166.3p Mjc=.4069 Vjc=.3905 Fc=.5 Cje=291.8p Mje=.3606 Vje=.75 Tr=10n Tf=1.551n Itf=1 Xtf=0 Vtf=10)

from Reddit.

Comment: I found this after 1 minute of googling:  https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/spice-model-for-toshiba-2sa1941-2sc5198.234901/

Answer (score 2):

A [forum website post](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/spice-model-for-toshiba-2sa1941-2sc5198.234901/post-3664091) gives the following without referencing any source, but perhaps it will help:

> From User "nnx" 2013-10-12 11:54:
>
> .model Q2sb772 PNP(Is=282f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=100 Bf=213.6 Ise=1.659p Ne=1.787 Ikf=6.472 Nk=.7894 Xtb=1.5 Var=100 Br=39.18 Isc=12.72p Nc=1.637 Ikr=.1652 Rc=64.89m Cjc=145.6p Mjc=.2985 Vjc=.3905 Fc=.5 Cje=255.3p Mje=.5064 Vje=1.615 Tr=10n Tf=1.927n Itf=6.218 Xtf=0 Vtf=10)

As well as the same NPN model you have:

> .model Q2sd882 NPN(Is=282f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=100 Bf=200.7 Ise=288.7f Ne=1.368 Ikf=20 Nk=1.235 Xtb=1.5 Var=100 Br=52.37 Isc=8.515p Nc=1.527 Ikr=.2617 Rc=15.88m Cjc=166.3p Mjc=.4069 Vjc=.3905 Fc=.5 Cje=291.8p Mje=.3606 Vje=.75 Tr=10n Tf=1.551n Itf=1 Xtf=0 Vtf=10)